# PHP and JSON entering inside a Div

Tags: php, html, css, json

So, I have a JSON array, which parses just fine in the layout view, but the elements from json stack vertically and I need them to be horizontally aligned.
Here is the example code

```
<div class="swiper-container mySwiper2 swiper-container-h">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-padding">
            <?php include_once("team_hq.php"); ?>

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide  swiper-padding bkg bkg3">
            <h2>Partners</h2>
            <?php 
            showStuff($stuff, "Partners"); ?>

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-padding bkg bkg12">
            <h2>Production</h2>
            <?php showStuff($stuff, "Production"); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide  swiper-padding bkg bkg13">
            <h2>Sales</h2>
            <?php showStuff($stuff, "Sales"); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide  swiper-padding bkg bkg14">
            <h2>Support</h2>
            <?php showStuff($stuff, "Support"); ?>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

The question I'm asking is how can I make the content which is pulled from the $stuff variable present horizontally instead of vertically as is now.

Comment: No you don't. You either have JSON, which is a single uninterrupted string that does nothing, or you parsed that JSON into "whatever programming language you're using" and it's now a normal object in that programming language. Also, note that if your question is "how do I make this HTML look right" the answer is to use CSS in combination with HTML elements best suited to capture what the content is (e.g. those divs should almost certainly be `<section>`) and the question will have nothing to do with PHP or JSON.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to PHP? Isn't this a pure CSS problem? Then please share the matching **generated** markup, along with the stylesheets, and remove the irrelevant tags

Answer (score -1):

To position HTML elements horizontal either use:

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [CSS-Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [Floating](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

But assuming your function `showStuff` just prints a JSON string, you'd have to work with your `$stuff` variable. E.g. loop over the it's content – with PHP I suppose – and build the HTML-Tags according your needs.

Comment: or because it's 2021, css grid, but this isn't an answer, this is a comment posted as an answer. If you want to write an answer, explain how to apply the techniques you link to, to the code the question was asking about.

Comment: Absolutely true, seems his question was not very clear.

Comment: making it even more important to comment first, to get them to clarify.